# What is the meaning of levy a fine

Tags: phrase-meaning, legalese

I came across the following ***[definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+levy+a+fine)***:

> To levy a fine - to commence and carry on a suit for assuring the
>   title to land or tenements.

But I've always thought it means something like is that you have to pay some money as a punishment, to avoid being jailed. What is the use case of it with this definition?

Comment: Did you check all the definitions of [levy](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/levy)? 1. or 3.? A fine is one option, but it is usually something of monetary value. I would question the quoted definition, citing a 1913 reference.

Comment: @user3169 - but it looks strange in the meaning "to commence and carry on a suit". I have never come across such usage..

Comment: See the source, the year is 1913.

Comment: It might be an outdated definition, as others have said, but it could also be legal jargon that's seldom heard in everyday parlance. I found this in a [2016 CNET article](http://www.cnet.com/news/apple-samsung-rival-xiaomi-readies-itself-for-us-battle/): _You've got the so-called patent trolls who buy up the rights to certain products or processes. "You have to be prepared to fight those," Barra said, as well as actual real competitors who might **levy a suit**._

Answer (score 2):

"To levy a fine" is a standard legal phrase meaning "to asses a fine" or 
"to impose a fine", that is for a court or other legal authority to require a person (or a business or organization) to pay a sum of money as a penalty.

It does not now mean "to commence and carry on a suit for assuring the title to land or tenements." and I do not believe that it ever did. I strongly suspect this was an error in the quoted source, perhaps a misprint where one definition was printed next to the wrong term. Errors do happen.

Note that a berm protecting land from flooding by a river or other body of water is known as a levy, mostly in the Southern US, because it was typically built with labor levied, or conscripted fo the purpose. The obligation to do the work was imposed, like a fine.

"Levy" was also used for a tax, and one still sees the term "school levy" used in official documents to mean a local tax to support a school district.  The term is no longer in common use outside of legalese. The tex was said to be "levied", that is. "imposed".

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is this:

> What is the use case of it with the definition [of something you have to pay some money as a punishment, to avoid being jailed]?

In this case, we're using the following:

- (Noun) An imposing or collecting, as of a tax or fine, by authority of force.
- (Noun) The amount owed or collected.

But that doesn't really explain things. To do so, you have to have a basic understanding of American civil and criminal law.

The court system (whether civil or criminal) has the power to impose a fine upon a person or virtual entity (like a company) that they must pay. If this fine is not paid on time, the court *may* (or in some cases *must*) issue a warrant for the arrest of the person who was fined. Let's give a simple example:

A person can receive a ticket for a traffic violation -- including (but not limited to) speeding, illegal parking, running someone repeatedly over with their car, having a headlight out -- for which the State may ***levy a fine***. This is the word *levy* as you were understanding it, as it can describe not only the act of imposing the fine, but also the amount owed for the fine, and the money eventually collected for said fine.

> But how does that answer the question? Why does it mean something you have to pay to avoid being jailed?

When a court levies a fine, it expects it to be paid. If you do not pay the fine by the date it is due, the fine can be increased, or the court may ***issue a summons or warrant of arrest for [your] appearance.*** ([Arizona Revised Statutes, Section 13-810](http://www.azleg.state.az.us/ars/13/00810.htm)) Essentially, your nonpayment of the fine is treated as a form of [contempt of court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contempt_of_court) and carries the same consequences.

If you want additional information, you can follow the links I've included in the articles, or do a Google search on subjects like "nonpayment of fines" or "bench warrant".

Answer (score 0):

The original definition is correct and because of the concept of 'cancel culture', in the strictest sense whereby new definitions overreach older definitions, we become subject to explaining equity primarily and not the law, from which equity sprang.

To bench or bar the entail interest, subject to the rules of inheritance in the common law, the purchaser of a legal interest in land would '**levy a fine**' so as to direct the attention of the court towards a new 'tripartite indenture', thereby overreaching the original legal estate deed held in the entail, which concluded a compromise and so thereby stood as fact, in the court's jurisdiction, which now no longer recognized the entail interest via this overreach. This scheme was used before the statute of De Donis was introduced and then again in the Statute of Fines 1488.

Excerpt from: 'Desmond H Brown, Historical Perspective on the Statute of Uses, 1979 9 Manitoba Law Journal 409, 1979 CanLIIDocs 142, https://canlii.ca/t/swjw

> While a bargain and sale or any other method of raising a use could be employed to convey equitable estates, to endure, such estates had to be raised by a person who held his land in fee simple. The individual who held in fee tail could make grants to uses but, unless his heirs agreed to such grants, they could, under the provisions of De Donis, recover the land in the courts after the death of their ancestor.
> 119 This situation prevailed well into the 15th century, by which time there was great opposition to entailed estates which were, in effect, perpetual interests in land.
> 120 Hence, bench, bar, and statute were combined to create devices to "bar the entail." Prior to De Donis one method of conveying land had been for the tenant to "**levy a fine**." This was a collusive action at law which was compromised, with the terms of the compromise then becoming the terms of the conveyance. It was brought about in the following manner: B wanted to buy, and A wanted to sell Backacre. They went to court, where B, who had paid for the land, claimed it was his; A denied this, and so the action proceeded. However, before judgment was given A and B asked leave to com­promise the issue, and provided the bench with the detail of their agreement. The object of the whole procedure was then drawn up by the court — a tripartite indenture — which set out the details of ownership. The "foot" of the indenture was retained by the court both as a permanent record of the transaction, and as the final concord (finalis concordia) to all actions pertaining to the land in question.
> 121 This device was specifically prohibited by De Donis, in respect of estates tail, but was brought back by the Statute of Fines in 1488 for the express purpose of barring entails.

Comment: I wondered if this might be a highly specialised legal definition, incomprehensible to most people. I think your answer would be greatly improved if you started by saying this, and attempted to explain the term in words that were not equally obscure. I took a law degree nearly 50 years ago, so I have some idea what "To bench or bar the entail interest" might mean (though I have never encountered "bench" in this sense), but most people will be completely baffled.

Comment: And so is my plight. Law described and used in modern day academia has nothing to do with a man's interest before those imposed under the Settled Estates Act, administrated by the high courts of chancery. I am speaking to a different subject matter which is not subject to a trust for sale, as is what the original definition seems to be alluding to and so further expressed in the extract I attached. 

One would have to return back to the original legal remainders, attached to the life estate to express the correct subject matter concerning what are the entail's interest being discussed.

Comment: This is a site about language, not about law - moreover, about language learners. Your highly technical language (in your comment, as well as your original asnwer) is hard for me to understand, a native English speaker with a law degree. I suspect it is impenetrable to most English speakers. I also find your reference to "cancel culture" irrelevant and tendentious.

Comment: Good point. I was answering and/or correcting the original comments concerning the definition provided in this thread. Cancel culture is suitable to the extent that the true definition was being lost in opinion, so thought to direct the reader to always consider this before they accept any opinion that serves to eliminate a definition; case in point. As for the language used, not learned in language and so thank you for your insight. I do wish though that the law extract I attached serves to assist the reader when considering the definition that was being dissected.